"Disks" gnome-disks-utility. Accidentally clicked the delete partition button, is it possible to undo?
I am running Ubuntu and have a disk that is not the OS disk, just other data and files. I accidentally clicked the "Delete Partition" button in the Disks app. Is there any way to undo that?

Nope. Unless you want to send it to a super expensive recovery company.

Have you rebooted? If not rebooted, use fdisk to manually recreate table posts by srs5694 post34 on page#4:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1668247 Suggest  in future using gparted from live installer as it has more steps. I just do not like Disks for just about anything other than quickly renaming a partition. And I normally can do that from command line.

If you only deleted a partition, and didn't do anything else to the disk, testdisk should work fine to recover it.

This question is similar to: How to recover a deleted NTFS partition with data. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
